# loop array of items in declarative pipeline using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins pipeline can you please provide below out by using groovy declarative pipeline and -D should be appended for every key.

Input request should be string `'''name= ram id = 123 role = IT'''` and output needed as `-Dname=ram -Did=123 -Drole=IT`

```
pipeline{
    agent any
     parameters {
         text defaultValue:  '''name = ram id = 123 role = IT]''', description: 'employee details', name : 'details'
        }
  environment {
    emp_details = "${env.details}"  
}
      stage('build') {
        steps{ 
         script{
        echo "dislay details, ${emp_details }"
          for(e in emp_details){
            print e + ":" + emp_details[e])
            }
          } 
       } 
   } 
}
```

Final output: `-Dname=ram -Did=123 -Drole=IT`

> error: No Such property: [ for class: java.lang.String

if passing input is not right, how can we pass it?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a String not an array, so first, you need to create an iterable list and modify each key by iterating.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
         text defaultValue:  '''[name = ram, id = 123, role = IT]''', description: 'employee details', name : 'details'
        }
  environment {
    emp_details = "${env.details}"  
}
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps{ 
              script{
                echo "dislay details, ${params.details}"
                def appendedString = ""
                // SInce it's a string we need get rid of [ and ] characters and then the spaces. 
                def lst = params.details.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z=,]+","").split(',')
                println lst
                for(e in lst){
                    print(e)
                    appendedString += "-D" + e + " ";
                    }
                println "Final String: " + appendedString;
                } 
           }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**
Update the split logic to support the new string. '''name = ram id = 123 role = IT'''

```
def lst = params.details.replaceAll("\\s=\\s", "=").split("\\s")
```

Comment: Thanks @ycr, Now my input should be like this -> 
parameters {
         text defaultValue:  '''name = ram 
    id = 123 
    role = IT''', description: 'employee details', name : 'details'
        }  
And Ouput should be same, can you pls provide the replaceAll logic and for loop

Comment: @deepuKumar I didn't get your comment. Did the answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Above logic is working, but when I was trying with this string input -> '''name = ram id = 123 role = IT''' without array and comma it's not getting above desired output.

Comment: @deepuKumar if the inpput is changing you may need to update the data split logic. Since you are defining the input, why not define something that is easily processable?

Comment: Can you please provide data split logic for new input and sry for inconvenience.

Comment: @deepuKumar you are welcome. If you found this or any other answer useful please consider marking them as accepted answers.